# Como puedo referencias el color rojo en una variable color()

Tags: processing

Quisiera cambiar el valor de una variable de tipo color, pero no se como hacerle referencia.

```
Color C1 = color(0, 0, 0);
void draw(){
   //Aquí intente hacerle referencia con un . y una letra pero no funciona
   C1 = color(C1.r, C1.g, C1.b + 1);
}
```

El lenguaje es el de Processing ".pde"

Comment: Segun la documentacion deberia ser con: red() , green() y blue() https://processing.org/reference/red_.html https://processing.org/reference/green_.html https://processing.org/reference/blue_.html

Answer (score 0):

Primero hay que sacar los valores individuales del color

1. Primera forma, haciendo uso de las funciones red, green, blue los cuales aceptan un solo parámetro de tipo color y representan los colores rojo, verde, y azul respectivamente.
   Para tu ejemplo...

   ```
   float red1=  red (C1);

   float green1= green (C1);

   float blue1= blue (C1);
   ```

Luego podrías re definir la variable C1 y modificar los valores que quieras... (**nota: estas funciones siempre devuelven valores float y si los usas en variables de tipo int dará resultados indeseados**)

2. Segunda forma, haciendo uso del operador right shift  (>>) y bit mask (&). Esta forma es mucho más rápida que la anterior y te dará directamente los valores en tipo int:

   ```
   int red2 = (C1 >> 16) & 0xFF;  
   int green2 = (C1 >> 8) & 0xFF;   
   int blue2 = C1 & 0xFF;  //solo bit mask

   C1= color (red2, green2, blue2+1);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
int red2 = (C1 >> 16) & 0xFF;  


 C1= color (red2)
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).